# Hamilton cycles in $\{0,1\}^n$ with fixed Hamming distance

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, hamiltonian-paths

Let $n>1$ be an integer. For $a,b\in \{0,1\}^n$ let $d_h(a, b)$ denote the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) of $a$ and $b$. For $k\in \{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ let $H(n,k)$ be the graph on $\{0,1\}^n$ given by the edge set $$E(n,k) = \{(a, b)\in (\{0,1\}^n)^2 : d_h(a, b) = k\}.$$

**Question.** For what values of $k\in \{2,\ldots n-1\}$ does $H(n,k)$ have a Hamilton cycle?

**Note 1.** Hamilton cycles in $H(n,1)$ are called *Gray codes*.

**Note 2.** A necessary (but maybe not sufficient) condition for $H(n,k)$ to have a Hamilton cycle is that $\text{gcd}(k,2^n) = 1$, otherwise $H(n,k)$ is not a connected graph.

Comment: Oh - right, will amend, thanks @MaxAlekseyev!

Comment: [Related open problem which may be of interest to you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_conjecture).

Comment: Thanks @PeterTaylor for pointing to this problem and making me aware that $H(n,k)$ is vertex-transitive!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe these are exactly odd $k$.

Indeed, it can be easily seen that if $k$ is even, then a cycle starting at $0^n$ can visit only those vectors that have even number of $1$'s, and so it cannot be Hamiltonian.

On the other hand, there exist [long-run Gray codes](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v10i1r27) where any consecutive $\leq n-3\log_2 n$ bit changes happening at distinct positions. So, for odd $k\leq n-3\log_2 n$ traversing such a code with step $k$ produces a Hamiltonian cycle in $H(n,k)$.

Also, for an even $n$, inverting every second element of a cycle in $H(n,k)$ produces a cycle in $H(n,n-k)$.

It remains to address the case of odd $n$ and odd $k>n-3\log_2 n$.

Comment: Very nice - thank you Max for this short argument!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a different perspective on the problem (which also settles the case left open by Max Alekseyev's answer).

$H(n,k)$ is a Cayley graph of the group $G = \{0,1\}^n$ with respect to the set $M_k$ of elements with exactly $k$ non-zero entries. It is well known (and easy to prove by induction on the number of generators) that any connected Cayley graph of an abelian group contains a Hamilton cycle. So we only need to check when $H(n,k)$ is connected, or equivalently, if $M_k$ is a generating set of $G$.

Note that any element of $M_2$ is the sum of two elements in $M_k$, hence $M_{k-2}$ is contained in the subgroup generated by $M_k$. If $k$ is odd, then this implies that $M_k$ generates $M_1$ and thus all of $G$. If $k$ is even, then (as noted by Max Alekseyev) $M_k$ generates the same subgroup of index $2$ as $M_2$.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Florian for this different take on the problem!